# How to show two table columns in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to show columns of two tables in my template, but I have not been successful

**Template :**

```
@foreach ($LatestSeeker_list_adv as $ads)
    <span>ads id</span><span>{{ $ads->advertise->id }}</span>
    <span>inf id</span><span>{{ $ads->information->id }}</span>
@endforeach
```

**Controller :**

```
public function SeekerLatest()
{
    $LatestSeeker_list_adv = Advertise_Model::all();

    return view('Users.Seeker.LatestAds.index',compact('LatestSeeker_list_adv','LatestSeeker_list_inf'));
}
```

**Advertise Model :**

```
public function Information()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Information_Model');
    }
```

**Information Model :**

```
public function Advertise()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Advertise_Model');
    }
```

**advertise migration :**

```
Schema::table('advertise', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('information_id')->references('id')->on('information');
        });
```

***EDIT :***

**error :**

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\Users\Aghapesae\Desktop\baroot\resources\views\Users\Seeker\LatestAds\Index.blade.php)

Comment: Please provide more detailled information on _why_ it is not working.

Comment: I edited my post and submit my error

Comment: Try to put a `dd($LatestSeeker_list_adv)` after `$LatestSeeker_list_adv = Advertise_Model::all();` in your controller. What does that give you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `with`

```
public function SeekerLatest()
{
    $LatestSeeker_list_adv = Advertise_Model::with('Information')->get();

    return view('Users.Seeker.LatestAds.index',compact('LatestSeeker_list_adv','LatestSeeker_list_inf'));
}
```

In view you can do like this :

```
@foreach ($LatestSeeker_list_adv as $ads)
    <span>ads id</span><span>{{ $ads->id }}</span>
    <span>inf id</span><span>{{ $ads->Information->id }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get this error with your code : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: Use get() instead of all() . Check I had edited my answer

Comment: I try to do this by get, but get this error ! : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'information.advertise__model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `information` where `information`.`advertise__model_id` in (1, 2))